# Python: Problem with plotting from one point in Y to many points on X axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have one point on Y axis and many on X axis and i want to do straight lines from this one Y point to each X (shape of triangle).

```py
plt.plot([P], [TR], 'k')
plt.xlabel('CENTERLINE')
plt.ylabel('RADIUS')
plt.show()
```

Where `TR` is my single point declared earlier and `P` are float points (first i create `P = np.zeros((n+1))` and after that using for loop i put there values).

`plt.show()` returns empty chart (without any plot)

[Here is the example how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdI36.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When handling many lines at once it may be a good idea to use a `LineCollection` object:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

import numpy as np

pos_fixed = np.array([0, 35])
lines = np.array([[[pos, 0], pos_fixed] for pos in np.arange(0, 50, 2)])
line_coll = LineCollection(lines)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(line_coll)

plt.xlim([0, lines[:,:,0].max()])
plt.ylim([0, lines[:,:,1].max()])
```

This way you can handle your plot more easily (and it's also faster if you have many lines).

Result:

[image]

Comment: can i change it somehow from ```plt.xlim([0, 50])
plt.ylim([0, 35])``` to 
```plt.xlim([0, P])
plt.ylim([0, TR])``` ?

Comment: You mean, that the limits can be autodetected? Well you could just choose the highest `x`/`y` value as the limit

Comment: autodetected or if i can set the limits with any variable like ```P``` or ```TR```. When i put ```plt.xlim([0, P]) plt.ylim([0, TR])```  there is an error   ```The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()```

EDIT: in Y axis always the highest will be TR and on X will be P, but their values are variable

Comment: Well that's most likely, because `P` and `TR` are not scalars but arrays?

Comment: Only P is array, but TR is intiger value

Comment: I've updated the answer, so that the program will automatically find the maximum for the limits from the provided `lines` array

Answer (score 1):

Those lines are not a contiguous plot, so you'll need to plot them separately.  You could make it a single line that goes up and down (and up and down and up and down...) but I think this makes more sense as separate lines.  Consider:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
originpoint = (0, 5)
yfloor = 0
xvalues = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for x in xvalues:
    plt.plot((originpoint[0], x), (originpoint[1], yfloor))
plt.show()
```

[image: the plot]